# adjusting display of array of users in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, infinite-scroll

Currently i am using knockout js to display users into a page and because the number of users could exceed 250 users I don't want to load all 250 at one time because 1- it won't fit all in once page 2- it will take time. I will using a scroll feature so when the user scrolls i will load more users to display.

Current code gets the length of all users which could be 250 or 500  and then displays 20 per page and paginate till the end.

**Problem** I would like to change the code in order that it will just pull the first 20 of users to display and when the user scrolls it will grab the next 20 - without having to count all users before loading.

**Knockout JS**

```
 var _rosterUsers = new Array();

$.views.Roster.RosterViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.RosterUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
    _rosterUsers = self.RosterUsers;
    self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
    self.toDisplay = ko.observable(20);
    filteredRoster = ko.computed(function(){
        var init = (self.currentPage()-1)* self.toDisplay(),
            filteredList = [],
            rosterLength = self.RosterUsers().length,
            displayLimit = self.toDisplay();
        if(rosterLength == 0)
            return[];
        for(var i = init; i<(displayLimit + init) - 1 && i<rosterLength; i++)
        {
            filteredList.push(self.RosterUsers()[i]);
        }
        return filteredList;
    }),
    totalRoster = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.RosterUsers().length;
    }),
    changePage = function (data) {
        self.currentPage(data);
    },
    next = function () {
        if ((self.currentPage() * self.toDisplay()) > self.RosterUsers().length)
            return;

        self.currentPage(self.currentPage() + 1);
    },
    prev = function () {
        if (self.currentPage() === 1)
            return;

        self.currentPage(self.currentPage() - 1);
    },

    $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
};
```

**Scroll JS in Knockout file**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        if (parseInt($.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.currentPage(), "10") * 20 < parseInt($.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.totalRoster(), "10")) {
            $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.next();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

koGrid.js is built for this but the server has to count the number of items. We use this tools with tables that have more than 20K entries and there is no performance hit. The queries executes in under a second.